# what is the meaning/purpose of xxxxxx="${xxxxxx/ /}" in bash command

Tags: bash

I'm quite new to bash script and trying to read a script and find some lines really confusing and hard to check on somewhere else
The part of script is like this:

```
normbiasread=`mas_param get tes_bias_normal`
normval=`echo "$normbiasread" | grep -o '\([0-9]*\)\s' | head -1
normval="${normval/ /}"
```

The first line is to read an array from a .config file and the second line is to chose the number+space pattern and only select the first component.
But I'm confused about the 3rd line since normval seems have already been defined to be a number on the 2nd line, and I don't know what is the meaning of "${normval/ /}"

Comment: I recommend reading this great tutorial: [wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace).

Answer (score 0):

This is parameter substitution. Here's a page with a great explanation: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html
So
Here's the relevant bit:

> `${var/Pattern/Replacement}`
>
> First match of Pattern, within var replaced with Replacement.
>
> If Replacement is omitted, then the first match of Pattern is replaced by nothing, that is, deleted.

So in this case, the first space in the captured output is removed.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter expansion `${something/ /}` will simply replace the first space within the `${something}` variable with the empty string.

Running `man bash` on your installation, and searching for the section entitled `parameter expansion` will tell you this and a great deal more about the sort of things you can do.

This is almost certainly to do with the fact that your `grep` search string is `'\([0-9]*\)\s'`, containing the whitespace-matching character `\s` at the end. The assumption that that matches an actual *space* is not something I would have made but the original author may have more information.